# Django пагинация с POST-запросами

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pagination

Мне нужно реализовать пагинацию в django v3.0.2.
Есть одна страница, на которой пользователь выбирает в селектах различные параметры и нажимает кнопку "Поиск". **Вот часть кода из шаблона страницы 1:**

```
<form novalidate id="myForm" method="POST" action="{% url 'select_params' %}">
{% csrf_token %}

<select class="dm" multiple="" name="t" required="" id="tSelect">
        {% for ts in ts_all %}
            <option value="{{ ts.id }}">{{ ts.runame }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

<select class="dm" multiple="" name="c" required="" id="cSelect">
        {% for cm in cm_all %}
            <option value="{{ cm.id }}">{{ cm.runame }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

<button type="submit" class="sd-button" id="sd-button">Поиск</button>
</form>
```

Пользователь должен попасть на новую страницу, где ему выдаются объекты согласно POST-запросу(стр.1) и на эти объекты работает пагинация. **Вот часть кода из шаблона страницы 2:**

```
{% for d in ds %}
    {{ d.runame }}
{% endfor %}

{% if ds.has_other_pages %}
    <ul class="pagination">
    {% if ds.has_previous %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ ds.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
{% endif %}

{% for i in ds.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if ds.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if ds.has_next %}
    <li><a href="?page={{ ds.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
{% else %}
    <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
{% endif %}

</ul>
{% endif %}
```

**Вот функция во views.py**, которая должна создавать пагинацию для страницы 2:

```
def search_params(request, page_number=1):

        q = request.POST

        c_value = q.getlist('c')
        t_value = q.getlist('t')

        c_value = c_value[-1] if c_value else C.objects.values().last()['id']
        t_value = t_value if t_value else T.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)

        ds_query = Dis.objects.filter(dis_c__ct__lte=c_value).filter(ts__id__in=taste_value).distinct()

        paginator = Paginator(ds_query, 2)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        ds = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        context = {'ds':ds}
        return render(request, 'funcs/d_query.html', context)
```

**Вот urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('dises', views.dises, name='dises'), #стр1
    re_path(r'^d_query/(\d+)/$', views.search_params, name='select_params'),#стр2

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Проблемы:**

1) В теге `<form>` на стр1 указан параметр `action="{% url 'select_params' %}"`, который в таком виде не работает, требует reverse match.

2) Сама пагинация отображается, если добавить цифру, например "1" к параметру `action="{% url 'select_params' 1 %}"`, но механизм пагинации не работает. Например, по нажатию на цифру "2" на странице с пагинацией - подгружается текущая страница, но вообще без объектов из БД.

**Вопрос:** Kак правильно организовать пагинацию в django, где есть форма с POST-запросом? Приведите, по возможности, примеры кода или поправьте мой. Буду вам премногоблагодарен, ибо впервые делаю пагинацию :)

*догадываюсь, что что-то надо во вьюхе делить на POST и GET, но не до конца соображаю

Comment: пагинация гет методом реализовывается, есть встроенный пагинатор в джанго

Comment: Ну это понятно, он у меня в функции выше как раз и прописан.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал, чувачеллы)

В общем-то, как и предполагалось, нужно отдельно обработать GET-запрос в принимающей функции.
Не уверен, что моё решение оптимально по ресурсам, но оно работает.

**Что я сделал**:

1) Добавляем в функцию во `views.py` обработку условий `if request.method == 'POST'` и `if request.method == 'GET'`.

2) Добавляем в сессию запроса новый параметр (далее в коде - `search`), в который сохраняем все выбранные пользователем параметры из POST-запроса.

3) При обработке GET-запроса(то есть пагинации) используем эти сохраненные данные из сессии, чтобы пагинатор выгрузил из базы данных нужные записи.

4) Всё, что я писал в вопросе про `action="{% url 'select_params' 1 %}"` забываем и меняем обратно на `action="{% url 'select_params' %}"`.

Теперь сам код. **views.py** в упрощенном виде:

```
def search_params(request, page=1):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        q = request.POST

        c_value = q.getlist('c')

        request.session['search'] = f'{c_value}' #это f-строка если чё

        ds_query = Dis.objects.filter(dis_c__ct__lte=c_value).distinct()

        paginator = Paginator(ds_query, 2)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        ds = paginator.get_page(page)

        context = {'ds':ds}
        return render(request, 'funcs/d_query.html', context)

    else:

        if 'search' in request.session:

                ds_query = Dis.objects.filter(dis_c__ct__lte=request.session['search']).distinct()

                paginator = Paginator(ds_query, 2)
                page = request.GET.get('page')
                ds = paginator.get_page(page)

                context = {'ds':ds}

                return render(request, 'funcs/d_query.html', context)
```

В **urls.py** убираем всю чушь с `re_path`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('dises', views.dises, name='dises'), #стр1
    path('d_query', views.search_params, name='select_params'), #стр2 измененный url

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Вот, как-то так, работает замечательно. При этом не могу сказать насчёт нагрузки на БД в таком случае, т.к. не знаю работу пагинатора изнутри. Если вы знаете более оптимальный и каноничный вариант - пишите, будет клёво изучить!